# Laravel Form Text Not Being Uploaded To Database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am trying to create a comment system for posts on a blog. I created a form for uploading a comment. Both the user_id and the post_id columns are properly populated in the table, however, the body column is empty when enter text and submit it. I defined a relationship that one Post hasMany Comments. Also, I defined that one User hasMany Comments. Here is my code:

```
//commentcontroller.php

public function newComment(){

        $id=Auth::id();

        $comment = New Comment();

        $comment->user_id=$id;
        $comment->post_id=Input::get('post_id');
        $comment->body=Input::get('body');

        post->comments()->save($comment);
}
```

Form:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

<hr>

@foreach($posts as $post)
    <h3>{{ $post->title}}</h3>
    <p>by {{ $post->user->name }}</p>
    <img src='{{ asset($post->image_path) }}' class="img-responsive" id="blogpic"/>
    <p>{{ Str::words($post->body) }}</p>
    <p><a href="{{ action('BlogController@show', $post->id) }}">Read More...</a></p>

    <hr>
            //COMMENT AREA
    {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'CommentController@newComment', 'files'=>true)) }}
            {{ Form::textarea('body', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('post_id', $post->id) }}

    <br>

    <br>


    {{ Form::submit('Post') }}

@endforeach

 </div>
```

I am not concerned yet about displaying comments, just uploading them to the database. The user_id and post_id upload correctly in the database, the text just doesn't save. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
public function newComment()
{
    $comment = New Comment();
    $comment->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->post_id = $post_id = Input::get('post_id');
    $comment->body = Input::get('body');

    Post::find($post_id)->comments()->save($comment);
}
```

Notice `Auth::user()->id` is used instead of `Auth::id()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but Laravel threw a parse error on the post->comments()->save($comment); line. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Thanks, the text uploads to the DB now. But for some reason, it sets every post_id as 2. Why would that be?

Comment: Not sure, probably there are some miss configuration in relationship or wrong data inserted in the save was not working properly, try again after deleting the records from the table and start from the beginning.

Comment: I just truncated the post table and then it worked again! Thanks for your help!